# Center $Z(G)$ is a group of even order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is the following statement is true/false?
>
> Let $G$ be a finite group with a unique element $x$ of order $2.$ Then the center $Z(G)$ is a group of even order.

My attempts :  I thinks this statement is True

Comment: Why do you think it is true? Have you computed the center for any such groups? Guesses aren’t attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! $x$ is a unique element of order $2$ implies $x \in Z(G)$, for, since $$\vert x \vert=\vert axa^{-1}  \vert$$ for all $a \in G$.
Therefore  $$2=\vert x \vert=\vert axa^{-1}  \vert$$ for all $a \in G$

But $x$ is a unique element of order $2$ implies $$x=axa^{-1}$$ for all $a \in G$, which implies $ax=xa $ for all $a \in G$, so $x \in Z(G)$ and so $2 \;\Big\vert\; \vert Z(G) \vert$, so  $\vert Z(G) \vert$ is even!